Google Sheets IMPORTXML - Scrape Exhibitor List
Screenshot of company names: Trying to scrape company names for my CRM (Google Sheets), but getting Formula Parse Error.
Website: https://exhibitormanual.oceanbusiness.com/
Tried to change child/class as a xpath quary parameter. Tried also IMPORTHTML.
Used code:
=importxml ("https://exhibitormanual.oceanbusiness.com/", "//*[@id="drts-platform-render-66fc2684827da-2-post-20696"]/div/div/div[2]/div1/a")
Formula parse Error.

I think this is how should the syntax look like: =IMPORTXML("https://exhibitormanual.oceanbusiness.com/", "//*[@id='drts-platform-render-66fc2684827da-2-post-20696']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a"). This eliminated parse error that you encountered.
However, it returns an N/A error indicating that it retrieves nothing from the link. It would be helpful if you can provide even at least a screenshot of what you were trying to retrieve from the site.

Screenshot attached


Here's one approach which pulls the 293 company names spread across 2 pages; some unwanted titles(top 11) are pulled as well. You can mess around with the code if you want a more targeted xpath:
=reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(2),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,importxml("https://exhibitormanual.oceanbusiness.com/?_page="&c&"&num=200&sort=post_title","//*[@title]"))))



Strangely I get the same #ERROR! (Formula parse Error)

likely your sheet locale uses semicolon convention

Yes! This was the issue. I switched from Norwegian to UK and the formula works! Thank you so much.

Citing rockinfreakshow. I modified his code and this effectively retrieves the company names listed on the website by using the data-name attribute:
Sample code
=REDUCE(TOCOL(, 1), SEQUENCE(2), LAMBDA(a, c, VSTACK(a, IMPORTXML("https://exhibitormanual.oceanbusiness.com/?_page="&c&"&num=200&sort=post_title", "//*[@data-name='entity_field_post_title']"))))

Sample Output

References: IMPORTXML, Xpath

Yes, as rockinfreakshow mentioned the code can be edited for more targeted xpath. Thank you for refining the formula.

As an alternative, the below Google-App-Script can be used, where 282 ea company names are listed on the sheet.
 function getCompanyNames() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange('A1:A').clearContent();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    var j= 0;

    for (var p = 1; p< 4; p++) { 
      var URL = "https://exhibitormanual.oceanbusiness.com/directory-exhibitor_li/?_page=" + p + "&num=100&sort=post_title";

      try {    
        var options = {
          muteHttpExceptions: true,       
            headers: {
              "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
            }        
        };

        var strHTML = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options).getContentText(); 

        /* Sample company name "ANB Sensors" can be extracted using "Regular Expressions" from: 
            ......... data-content-type="directory__listing" data-content-name="exhibitor_li_dir_ltg">ANB Sensors</a></div>
        */

        var regex = new RegExp('(?<=data-content-name="exhibitor_li_dir_ltg">)(.+)(?=<\/a><\/div>)', 'gi');
        var dataMatch= strHTML.match(regex);

        Logger.log(dataMatch.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < dataMatch.length; i++) {             
          var data = dataMatch ? dataMatch[i] : "No data found";

          j++;
          
          sheet.getRange(j, 1).setValue(data);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log("Error: " + e.toString());
      }      
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Browser.msgBox(j + ' ea. company names are listed on the sheet')
 }

.

